# How to avoid text wrapping in VS2012 editor for .html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I want to avoid text wrapping in VS2012 editor for .html files, it's really annoying.

For all the other files format, for example .cs / .vb files, I don't have this problem: every line in the editor exactly corresponds to a single line in the file.

Resharper doesn't have text wrapping option for .html file, so...

[image]
[image: missing option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I have no idea about ReSharper, try this:

Tools -> Options ->

[image: word-wrap]

Comment: worked perfectly, even if I have resharper installed. thank you